# How to access multiple tenants in eclipselink?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, multi-tenant

Tenants in eclipselink (or Hibernate) are a great concept to separate data domains from each other. I am using eclipselink with single-table strategy.

Sometimes it is necessary to access data from more than just one tenant (e.g. for admin purposes). Is there a good way to achieve that? (I do not want to run through all tenants to collect the data...)

Example:

```
@Entity
@Multitenant
@TenantDiscriminatorColumn(name = "TENANT", contextProperty = "tenant.id")
public class TenantEntity {
    ...
```

I can access the objects in a specific tenant with a parameterized entity manager:

```
private static EntityManager newEntityManager(String tenant) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("tenant.id", tenant);
    return emf.createEntityManager(map);
}
```

Is there any convenient way to query over all tenants? (Or is the identity of a persisted object only defined in a single tenant?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EclipseLink has an open feature request to allow a better way of allowing an admin server to access multi tenant data: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=355458 - vote for it if it is important to you.

The way around it would be to create a separate persistence unit for your admin console.  One way to go about this would be to move the multitenant metadata to an EclipseLink orm.xml file, and use it in your tenant persitence units, while the admin persistence unit just use the entity classes.  You might want a field in the entities that can be mapped to the tenant column that the admin console could use and query against, but be read-only or inaccessible to the tenant specific persistence units.

Comment: Great hint, thanks. So - it is an open problem to do this straight forward. And the accepted work-around is to use two separate persistance units.
This also means that identity is guaranteed over multiple tenants (there is only one object of a specific class with a specific id over all tenants).

Comment: Does this approach with several persistance units also work with annotations? Do you have any hints for me?

Comment: Annotations are in the shared classes, so would get picked up by both persistence units.  Anything specific to one persistence unit should be moved to orm.xml that is only included in that persistence unit.  Orm.xml allows overriding annotations, but I am not sure how to override tenant annotations, so you may have to put them in the tenant specific eclipselink-orm.xml.

Answer (score 2):

I found an alternative approach that I will try out: Instead of using the @Multitenant annotation to filter out those entities that belong to my tenant I will use @AdditionalCriteria. My example from the question above becomes

```
@Entity
@AdditionalCriteria(":ADMINACCESS = 1 or this.tenant=:TENANT")
public class TenantEntity {

    private String tenant;
    ...
```

Here I need to take care of the tenant column myself.
I can create two entity managers. One for tenant access:

```
private static EntityManager newEntityManager(String tenant) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("TENANT", tenant);
    map.put("ADMINACCESS", 0);
    return emf.createEntityManager(map);
}
```

And another one for admin access:

```
private static EntityManager newEntityManager() {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("TENANT", "");
    map.put("ADMINACCESS", 1);
    return emf.createEntityManager(map);
}
```

See details for @AdditionalCriteria [here](https://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_additionalcriteria.htm). Any comments?

Comment: Your tenant field is now completely the responsibility of the application.  While a tenant cannot read other tenant data through entities, the application logic itself needs to be sure to prevent tenants from writing to the wrong tenant or leaving the tenant field blank.  You will have to make sure the entity is not cached in the 2nd level shared cache as well.

Comment: Yes, correct. You need strong mechanisms to prevent from breaking out of the tenant sandbox. I haven't finished it yet, but that seems to be feasible. I have a thread-local entity manager that knows its tenant. It controls all actions and e.g. sets tenant values on persist. So the persist method (and similar actions) does not require a tenant and neather the entity itself. The tenant logic is encapsulated pretty low level. Well, I hope that works. I haven't thought through the 2nd lecel cache implications yet.

Comment: @FrankHenningsen just wondering how this went. I'm trying to solve the same issue. I don't suppose you have any code you would be willing to share :)