# EclipseLink: How to turn off Multi-Tenancy even If I annotate Entity with @MultiTenant

Tags: java, eclipselink, multi-tenant

I am using EclipseLink for Single Table Multi-Tenancy.

I have annotated entities with @Multi-Tenant and everything is working fine.

Is it possible to turn off Multi-Tenancy without any change?.

I know there is a `org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.Multitenant.includeCriteria()` which I can set turn off to disable Multi-tenancy.

But my solution is packaged and delivered as a Package mode and there is no any way to set above attribute to false.

What I want, even I annotated Entity with `@Multi-Tenant` annotation and even there is a column `TENANT_ID` in database, 
but if I does not set `PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT` than it should not throw below exception and any CRUD operation should be succeed.

```
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-6174] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: No value was provided for the session property [eclipselink.tenant-id]. This exception is possible when using additional criteria or tenant discriminator columns without specifying the associated contextual property. These properties must be set through Entity Manager, Entity Manager Factory or persistence unit properties. If using native EclipseLink, these properties should be set directly on the session.
```

So, is there any way or any customization/extension point(s) so that If I set

```
PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT
```

then It should include `TENANT_ID` as an criteria and if I not set than simply it should not include `TENANT_ID` as an criteria?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an open issue for eclipselink. I have posted a similar question [lately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22493607/2690909). Chris posted an helpful answer with a link to a [feature request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22536079/2690909). A workaround described there is the usage of multiple persistence units for the same tables with different multi tenancy settings.

I am trying to use an [alternative approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22547545/2690909): Instead of @Multitenant I use @AdditionalCriteria. This annotations enables you to define your own request criteria added to any database operation (with few exceptions like native SQL).

Example:

```
@AdditionalCriteria(":ADMINACCESS = 1 or this.tenant=:TENANT")
```

On creation of your entity manager you set the parameters. You could either provide a tenant of switch off multi tenancy. The drawback here is that you are responsible for the tenant attribute.

Comment: Thanks Frank, the drawback is not tolerable as I do not want to be responsible to manage tenant attribute. Any other alternatives if you can suggest?

Comment: Well, did you take a look at the links I mentioned above? The alternative described there is using two persistence units addressing the same tabels. One uses the @Multitenant attribute, the other one does not.

Comment: Yes...but I can't do that...as I do not want to replicate entities.... Is there any way that Even annotation is there and if I do not set TENANT_ID , it should simply ignore it and proceed it as a non multi tenant environment

Comment: This is the way I would want to have it, too. It seems that there is no way for it. Just to be sure: The suggestion above (that I have not tried out, yet) is not about replicating entities. You would define the entity metadata not as annotation but instead in external files. And you would use two different meatdata definitions for your two cases (tenant access and tenant free access). Depending on which factory you are using the according definition is used.

Comment: ok.got your point. Thanks for help. Yes no need to replicate entities if I use external ORM file for metadata.

Answer (score 0):

There is another workaround to this problem.
You can use an Eclipselink MetadataSource to override at runtime the annotations in the entity class and to pretend that you use a dedicated database per tenant, for example:

```
  MultitenantMetadata md = new MultitenantMetadata();
  md.setIncludeCriteria(false);
  md.setType(MultitenantType.TABLE_PER_TENANT.name());
  TenantTableDiscriminatorMetadata td = new TenantTableDiscriminatorMetadata();
  td.setType(TenantTableDiscriminatorType.SCHEMA.toString());
  td.setContextProperty(DISCRIMINATOR_SCHEMA_PROPERTY);
  md.setTenantTableDiscriminator(td);
  entityAccessor.setMultitenant(md);
```

The above will make Eclipselink happy from a multi-tenancy point of view, but your tables may still have the discriminator column if your annotations specify that multi-tenancy is achieved using a discriminator column.

To remove the discriminator column you can use a SessionCustomizer that manipulates the EclipseLink representation of the entities before the EMF is created in order to:

- Remove the discriminator column
- Change indices and foreign keys to remove any reference to the discriminator column.

In this way the database tables and the DDLs will no more include the discriminator column.

```
        Set<String> discriminatorColumnNames = getDiscriminatorColumns(descriptor);

        for (DatabaseTable databaseTable : descriptor.getTables()) {
            List<IndexDefinition> indexDefinitions = databaseTable.getIndexes();
            for (Iterator<IndexDefinition> definitionIt = indexDefinitions.iterator(); definitionIt.hasNext();) {
                IndexDefinition indexDefinition = definitionIt.next();
                // remove qualifier from index to prevent a syntax error in DDL
                indexDefinition.setQualifier("");
                for (Iterator<String> fieldNameIt = indexDefinition.getFields().iterator(); fieldNameIt.hasNext();) {
                    if (discriminatorColumnNames.contains(fieldNameIt.next().toUpperCase())) {
                        fieldNameIt.remove();
                    }
                }
                if (indexDefinition.getFields().isEmpty()) {
                    definitionIt.remove();
                }
            }

            Map<String, List<List<String>>> uniqueConstraints = databaseTable.getUniqueConstraints();
            for (Entry<String, List<List<String>>> uc : uniqueConstraints.entrySet()) {
                List<List<String>> strings = uc.getValue();
                for (List<String> list : strings) {
                    String found = null;
                    for (String string : list) {
                        if (discriminatorColumnNames.contains(string.toUpperCase())) {
                            found = string;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (found != null) {
                        list.remove(found);
                    }
                }

            }

        }
```