# How To Implement Dynamic Multitenancy Or Dynamic Table Filtering with JPA/EclipseLink?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, multi-tenant

I have a JavaEE 6, JPA 2.1 application where I need administrative
users to belong to multiple tenants. This is required so that they are
for example able to change ownership of data from one tenant to
another.

The tenant structure is set up in a hierarchical way, following a tree
like implementation like this (format is `[Role:Tenant-ID]` for
reference):

```
                [SysAdmin:1]
                   /   \
                  /     \
                 /       \
                /         \
               /           \
  [Admin Tenant A:2]   [Admin Tenant B:3]
           / \               \
          /   \               \
 [User TA:4] [Manager TA:5] [User TB:6]
                \
                 \
             [User TA:7]
```

Now when I query the database with the active user `[User TA:4]` I
expect results with 'tenant-id' 4. When I query with the active user
`[Admin Tenant B:3]` I expect results to be from tenants 3 and 6 and
when I query as `[SysAdmin:1]` I simply want all data to be returned
basically without a filter.

As I have EclipseLink 2.5.1 as JPA implementation I tried utilizing
the `@Multitenant` implementation at first, which obviously does not
seem to work as it is expected to work for a single Tenant at a time
only, which makes perfect sense as it is using  that information for
actualy writes to the database as well.

For *writing* to the database I think I could manage to get something
along the lines of a custom `@Produces @MultitenantWriteAware
EntityManager` method thing going, where I assign the
`eclipselink.tenant-id` to the target tenant for write
operations. With that approach you however lose the nice container
managed `@PersistenceContext` (CMT) as you `@Inject` your
`EntityManager` then.

When trying to implement this with a custom `PersistenceProvider` that
piggybacks on the one EclipseLink provides I faced problems as I could
not retrieve the active user from anywhere. The only way to pass that
information seems to be through the supplied `Map` in

```
public
EntityManagerFactory 
createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitInfo info, Map properties)
```

I also looked into `QueryRedirector`s which seem to let me customize
the query and append a condition like 'AND tenant_id IN (2,3,4)' into
the active query, which is the somewhat manual way of implementing
(multi) `@Multitenant`, but I could not get that working either as I
didn't get far with that `ExpressionBuilder` and additionally seem to
be unable to query that active user from somewhere.

I think I have overlooked something, as I think there must be a sort
of generic and automatic way to implement this instead of manually
appending the extra conditions to the query using the
`CriteriaBuilder`

Is there any advise/tips/links/best practises on how to achieve this 
kind of setup?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is an open issue so far. I have posted a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22493607/2690909). One answer contained a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22536079/2690909) to the eclipse bug tracker raising this point, too. A workaround described there is the usage of multiple persistence units for the same tables with different multi tenancy settings. Depending on the EntityManagerFactory you are using the database queries have different scopes. I have not used that in practice (I am scared of potential inconsistencies in these two persistence units).

I am trying to use a different approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22547545/2690909) with @AdditionalCriteria. I add that annotation to all entities that should be filtered by tenant, but also should be accessible by an admin:

```
@AdditionalCriteria(":ADMINACCESS = 1 or this.tenant=:TENANT")
```

The flag ADMINACCESS decides whether the tenant filter is applied or not. I guess you can easily extend that to your scenario. That way it is guaranteed that this dynamic filter is always applied. But you need to take care of the tenant attribute yourself. For me this is a good compromise. I encapsulate all database actions in a single point. One way to achieve that in a uniform way is to remember the current tenant in the ThreadLocal EntityManager and to make sure that all tenant relative entities implement an interface TenantSpecific that defines a method setTenant(String tenant). This will always be set if you persist new objects.

Comment: This way you disable shared cache when you're joining tables with this annotation. Do you know how to set additional criteria when JPA queries cache?